# Calc/Excel aggregating data with same ID

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice, openoffice-calc

Hello i have to solve this problem in Libreoffice Writer or excel.
I have a table like this:

```
ID   V1   V2   V3  ...
1    10   20   30  ...
1    30   40   50  ...
1    5    7    8   ...
..   ..   ..   ..  ...
2    10   11   12  ...
1    5    4    1   ...
```

With a big (but fixed) number of rows and columns, i want to produce something like:

```
ID   V1   V2   V3  ...
1    45   67   88  ...
2    15   15   13  ...
```

Basically i'm going to sum up every value of each row that shares the first value (ID)

How can i do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: where i can find more information about it?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Comment: PivotColumns in Power Query can also help you get the result: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Calc, you can create a pivot table as follows:

1. Select your complete data range;
2. Menu Data -> Pivot Table -> Insert or Edit; select "Current selection", click <kbd>OK</kbd>
3. Defne the Pivot Table Layout:

   a. Draw "ID" from "Available Fields" to "Row Fields";

   b. Draw "V1", "V2" and "V3" from "Available Fields" to "Data Fields". Calc will automatically offer to sum the aggregated field values.

   c. Optionally, check "Options" if you want to add filters or anything else;

   d. By default, the created pivot table will be placed on a new sheet; to modify this, select the appropriate options under "Destination" (optionally).

   [image]
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> - that's all, here's your resulting table:

   [image]